# Heap sort worst case

Tags: heap-sort

I am really confused about this. I am trying to prove that the worst case of heap sort is Ω(nlogn) but i don't even know how to start.

Comment: Do you know the running-time of the operations of a heap and the sorting lower bound?

Comment: Sorting lower bound for comparison based sorting to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

After the build-up phase of the heap, HeapSort repeatedly removes the root of the heap. You can find configurations such that every root removal implies the movement of nodes on every level, resulting in a total work proportional to $\log(n)+\log(n-1)+\dots+ \log(1) \sim \log(n!)$.

Answer (score -3):

Write code for heap sort or copy it from somewhere and run some tests to make sure it is correct.

Then analyse the code. You will find there are lots of operations that run in O(log n), and you’ll need O(n) of them.